# Get collection from firestore, .map doesn't work (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Flutter with firebase for my app.

I started my application by putting all my code in the main. dart
I now want to organize my files well but I am facing a problem.

I created a service folder, with a database. dart file in which I made a class to find my items in firestorm

the problem is that I do not pass in the snapshot. docs.map ((doc))

here is my code in database. dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutterfirebase/models/todo_model.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  DatabaseService();

  final CollectionReference itemsCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("items");

  Stream<List<TodoItem>> get todos {
    return itemsCollection.snapshots().map((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      inspect(snapshot.docs);
      return snapshot.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        print('here');
        inspect(doc);
        return TodoItem(text: doc.data()['text'], done: doc.data()['done']);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

the  `print(snapshot.docs.length);`  returns 4. The  `inspect(snapshot.docs)`  works, I can see my 4 queryDocumentSnapshot with my id

but the  `print('here')`  does not appear, nor the  `inspect(doc)`

can you help me figure out what's going on, please?

here are the versions of the packages

firebase_core: ^1.0.2

cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3

Thanks

Comment: Maybe that's because doc type is `QueryDocumentSnapshot` and not a `DocumentSnapshot`, did you try that?

Comment: I tried too and the result is exactly the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should return QuerySnapshot from the stream not DocumentSnapshot, just like this

```
Stream<List<TodoItem>> getSomeoneItems() {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items')
    .snapshots()
    .map((qSnap) =>
        qSnap.docs.map((doc) => TodoItem.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
}
```

then you can use this stream in your view inside StreamBuilder widget.